# How to create zoomed plot window inside a main plot in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, bar-chart

[I would like a figure similar like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Q7YP.jpg)

Here is my data. Any sort of help highly appreciated.

| Model | RS | GS | BO | TPOT | OPTUNA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| RF | 0.8 | 0.81 | 0.82 | 0.91 | 1.35 |
| XGB | 0.45 | 0.37 | 1.65 | 0.63 | 0.2 |
| SVR | 1.59 | 1.59 | 1.65 | 0.65 | 0.39 |
| DT | 0.98 | 0.65 | 1.17 | 0.64 | 4.03 |
| GB | 0.5 | 0.55 | 0.75 | 0.64 | 0.82 |
| GPR | 1.06 | 1.06 | 1.06 | 0.64 | 12.23 |
| Huber | 0.6 | 0.6 | 0.6 | 0.64 | 0.58 |
| LR | 0.66 | 0.66 | 0.66 | 0.64 | 0.66 |
| DNN | 20.01 | 19.76 | 40.4 | 0.64 | 19.09 |

I have tried the following code. But didn't get what i expected. I am a beginner in python. Advance thanks for the support.

```
#import libraries
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import inset_axes
plt.rcParams['font.family'] = 'DeJavu Serif'
plt.rcParams['font.serif'] = ['Times New Roman']

data = '/content/Training-MAE.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(data)

#plot grouped bar chart

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

df.plot(x='Model', kind='bar', stacked=False, ax=ax).set(xlabel=" ", ylabel = " ")

axins = ax.inset_axes([0.1, 0.5, 0.4, 0.4]) # enlargement area

x1, x2, y1, y2 = 'RF','DNN', 0, 1
axins.set_xlim(x1, x2)
axins.set_ylim(y1, y2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to plot something on `axins`:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

df.plot(x='Model', kind='bar', stacked=False, ax=ax).set(xlabel=" ", ylabel = " ")

axins = ax.inset_axes([0.1, 0.5, 0.4, 0.4]) # enlargement area

df.plot(x='Model', kind='bar', stacked=False, ax=axins, legend=False)

x1, x2, y1, y2 = 'RF','DNN', 0, 1
axins.set_xlim(x1, x2)
axins.set_ylim(y1, y2)

# extend xlim to have extra space
x1, x2 = axins.get_xlim()
axins.set_xlim(x1-0.5, x2+0.5)
```

Output:

[image]